# How to get range that has been moved?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I am getting the range A2:B2:

```
sheet.getRange("A2:B2").getValues();
```

But I added a row under A1:B1, so now my values are in A3:B3

Is it possible for Apps Script to dynamically catch that my values are now on another range ?

If not, any alternative ideas on how I can dynamically get the range of moving rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to know whether the values of a range of "A2:B2" is moved.

In this case, how about using the named range, OnChange trigger, and PropertiesService? I thought that when those are used, your goal might be able to be achieved. When the sample script is prepared, it becomes as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create a named range.

As a sample, please create a named range to the cells "A2:B2" as "sampleNamedRange1". [Ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175)

#### 2. Prepare sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, [please install OnChange trigger to the function `installedOnChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```js
function installedOnChange(e) {
  var originalRange = "A2:B2";
  var nameOfNamedRange = "sampleNamedRange1";

  if (!["INSERT_ROW", "REMOVE_ROW"].includes(e.changeType)) return;
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var pv = p.getProperty("range");
  if (!pv) pv = originalRange;
  var range = e.source.getRangeByName(nameOfNamedRange);
  var a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  if (a1Notation != pv) {
    p.setProperty("range", a1Notation);
    Browser.msgBox(`Range was changed from ${pv} to "${a1Notation}". Original range is "${originalRange}".`);
  }
  // var values = range.getValues(); // The values are not changed because of the named range.
}
```

#### 3. Testing.

In this case, please do `I added a row under A1:B1`. By this, the script is automatically run by the OnChange trigger. And, you can see the dialog. You can see the demonstration as shown in the following image.

[image]

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [getRangeByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename)
- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

### Added:

From the discussions, I understood that you wanted to retrieve the named range of the specific sheet using the name of the named range. In this case, the sample script is as follows.

#### When the sheet name is used

```js
const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheetName").getRange("nameOfNamedRange");
```

or

```js
const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheetName").getNamedRanges().find(n => n.getName() == "nameOfNamedRange").getRange();
```

#### When the active sheet is used

```js
const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("nameOfNamedRange");
```

or

```js
const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges().find(n => n.getName() == "nameOfNamedRange").getRange();
```

Comment: That's not my goal but thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `That's not my goal but thanks for your effort.`, in order to correctly understand your goal, can you provide the detail of it? By this, I would like to confirm it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and no need to apologize for your english skill. I want to dynamically assign a value to getRange when the Values change. Just like the behavior of Excel/Sheets when a cell is linked to another cell through a formula. When you move this cell in Excel/Sheets, the formula inside the other cell readjusts to get the new cell. I'm asking if this is possible in Apps Script. Clear ?

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to dynamically assign a value to getRange when the Values change.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? When I could correctly understand it, I can look for a solution or a workaround.

Comment: what I mean by that is, just like how excel or Google Sheet saves a cell reference when moving a formula from one cell to another, I am wondering if getRange can also havr this behavior and automatically change getRange values when values change. Taking back my example, if my A2:B2 values are now A3:B3, can the getRange value automatically change from A2:B2 to A3:B3 ? So my goal is for getRange to automatically change the values when the values change.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `if my A2:B2 values are now A3:B3, can the getRange value automatically change from A2:B2 to A3:B3 ?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, can you provide the sample input and output you expect as the images? By this, I would like to try to understand it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can provide an image to that but here's what I am trying to do: initial values are in A2:B2 , so in Apps script it looks like: sheet.getRange("A2:B2").getValues(); Now my values are in A3:B3, so in Apps Script, I want it to automatically change to: sheet.getRange ("A3:B3").getValues(); - This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. From your reply, in your goal, when the cells of "A2:B2" on the sheet are moved to "A3:B3", you want to retrieve the value from the moved cells of "A3:B3". In this case, the value is not changed between "A2:B2" and "A3:B3". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Yes that's right

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that the named range can be used. The named range can chase the cells even when the cells are moved. When the named range is used, your goal can be achieved. And, when you check the current range from the named range, the method of `getRangeByName` can be used.

Comment: Thanks but Named ranges are set on the Spreadsheet, not on a Sheet.
As such, getRangeByName() is a function on the Spreadsheet class. You can't call it against a sheet.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Thanks but Named ranges are set on the Spreadsheet, not on a Sheet. As such, getRangeByName() is a function on the Spreadsheet class. You can't call it against a sheet.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Meaning it will only work on the active Sheet correct ? You cannot use this with getSheetbyName.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Meaning it will only work on the active Sheet correct ? You cannot use this with getSheetbyName.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Karim From `Yes that's right`, I have thought that in your goal, when the cells of "A2:B2" on the sheet are moved to "A3:B3", you want to retrieve the value from the moved cells of "A3:B3", and in this case, the value is not changed between "A2:B2" and "A3:B3". Is my umderstanding not correct?

Comment: @Karim When I could correctly understand your expected goal, I think that I might be able to think of a solution and a workaround. But, in the current stage, I cannot still understand your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, when you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: You have clearly understood my goal. I am just saying that , the getRangeByName() method is only available from a Spreadsheet object and not a Sheet object. So in order to apply the getSheetbyName, I need to write a script for the active sheet and not for a specific sheet using getSheetbyName. Am I right ?

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. For example, when you want to use the named range of the active sheet, you can retrieve the range using `const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges().find(n => n.getName() == "nameOfNamedRange")`. Is this your expected goal?

Comment: @Thanks but I am asking if I want  to use the named range for another sheet than the active sheet. Can I use it with getSheetByName ?

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but I am asking if I want to use the named range for another sheet than the active sheet. Can I use it with getSheetByName ?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I am asking if: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("name").getRangeByName("name"); Is this a possible function ?

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. About `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("name").getRangeByName("name"); Is this a possible function ?`, this cannot be used. Because `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet` is not used as a function. And also, `getRangeByName` is not the method of Class Range. So, can I ask you about the detail of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("name").getRangeByName("name")`?

Comment: Basically I am just asking whether I can use getRangeByName only for the active sheet of the active spreadsheet ? Or can I use it for a specific sheet of the active spreadsheet ?

Comment: @Karim For example, your expected result might be as follows? `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheetName").getRange("nameOfNamedRange")` or `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheetName").getNamedRanges().find(n => n.getName() == "snameOfNamedRange").getRange()`. If you want to use the active sheet, it's `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("nameOfNamedRange")` or `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges().find(n => n.getName() == "snameOfNamedRange").getRange()`.

Comment: Ok cool so I can use getSheetByName with getRangeByName, that was my question. You answered it. Thanks for your time I appreciate it.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added the script of your expected result in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I suppose when you wrote "snameOfNamedRange" , you meant "nameOfNamedRange" . The "s" is a typo. In any case that's correct. Marking it as answered

Comment: I'm the one that thanks you. I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your goal by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike Just to explain what @Karim requested at first: In sheets, say, A1: `=A2/2`. Now, a row is added above row2. A1 "automatically" becomes `=A3/2`(A2 becomes A3 automatically). Karim wanted a similar procedure, where `.getRange('A2')` automatically becomes `.getRange('A3')` on adding a row. This is just for your  explanation. Named range works. Please don't edit or add a new answer. @Karim This is the sample input and expected output requested by Tanaike.

Comment: @TheMaster I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `Please don't edit or add a new answer.`, in this case, I have to delete my answer. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Forget English...When have I ever asked you to delete your answer? Usually when I comment something, you would edit your answer with "some new techniques". I just said - since the answer is accepted, don't overthink or edit in a new answer.. Don't modify the answer, because I made a comment... Cheers.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, I understood it. In that case, for example, how about including it in "Note" section or "Supplement" section?

Comment: @Tanaike No worries. You don't need to change the answer, because of me. But if you want to, you're free to do so.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I understood `No worries. You don't need to change the answer, because of me. But if you want to, you're free to do so.`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through [DeveloperMetadata](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata?hl=en). Metadata can be set to ranges or sheets and whenever such data(ranges or sheets) are moved, the associated metadata moves along with it as well. Unfortunately, this metadata cannot be set to arbitrary ranges, but only to single column or single row. For eg, with `A2:B2`, We have to set the metadata to the entirety of column A, column B and Row 2. However, once set, apps script is no more needed. Google sheets automatically keeps track of the movements of such data.

#### Sample script:

```
const setDevMetadata_ = (sheetName = 'Sheet1', rng = '2:2', key = 'a2b2') => {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getRange(rng)
    .addDeveloperMetadata(key);
};

/**
 * @description Set metadata to a specific range
 * Unfortunately, this metadata cannot be set to arbitrary ranges, but only to single column or single row.
 * For eg, with `A2:B2`, We have to set the metadata to the entirety of column A, column B and Row 2.
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73376887
 */
const setDevMetadataToA2B2 = () => {
  ['2:2', 'A:A', 'B:B'].forEach((rng) => setDevMetadata_(undefined, rng));
};

/**
 * @description Get a range with specific developer metadata key
 */
const getRangeWithKey = (sheetName = 'Sheet1', key = 'a2b2') => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName),
    devFinder = sheet.createDeveloperMetadataFinder(),
    [rows, columns] = ['Row', 'Column'].map((rc) =>
      devFinder
        .withKey(key)
        .withLocationType(
          SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType[rc.toUpperCase()]
        )
        .find()
        .map((devmetadata) =>
          devmetadata.getLocation()[`get${rc}`]()[`get${rc}`]()
        )
    );

  console.log({ rows, columns });
  const rng = sheet.getRange(
    rows[0],
    columns[0],
    rows[1] ? rows[1] - rows[0] + 1 : 1,
    columns[1] ? columns[1] - columns[0] + 1 : 1
  );
  console.log(rng.getA1Notation());
  return rng;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the title and for responding. You seem to have understood my need. But you are saying that with your solution, Apps Script is no more needed. The purpose of my question, is to have the getRange values automatically get assigned to the new values when adding/removing the rows. Just like how Excel/Google sheets behaves when you move a cell that has a link with another cell through a formula. Excel/Sheets automatically assigns to the new cell. This is what I would like to replicate in Apps Script.

Comment: @Karim To get a range, there are many ways. The common way is to call `.getRange()` with a1notation `.getRange('a2:b2')`. Otherways include  row column: like `.getRange(2,1,1,2)`. In my example, we are using  calling using a developermetadata key: `getRangeWithKey('Sheet1', 'a2b2')`. For this to return the range properly, A metadata key should have been already set using `setDevMetadataToA2B2()`.  However, Those strings in code is not going to change automatically. You maybe able to use @Tanaike 's code with [tag:google-apps-script-api]  to achieve the same result, but it's complicated

Comment: thanks again for your response. From what I understand from you, it's not as easy as it seems and may not even be doable (for getRange to readjust to the new values automatically). Thanks for letting me know and for your time. Sure I asked the other guy maybe his input can give me more ideas on some alternatives.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that my question has been answered. I wasn't aware of getRangeByName which tracks the named range wherever it moves. Tanaike answered it and I marked it as answered. I just wanted to let you know that and to thank you again for your time and answer.

Comment: @Karim ````Great!````

Comment: I hope you are doing well! If you have time to check my new question I'd be very grateful. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675577/nested-forloop-not-properly-iterating-charts