# nested forLoop not properly iterating charts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that creates a Google Slide for every Google Sheets row. I want to add a single chart in each of the slides.

**The problem:**

My nested forLoop is putting **all** the charts inside **each** slide

**What I want to achieve:**

I want **each** chart to be individually on **each** created slide, such as **chart[0]** to be on **slide[0]**, **chart[1]** to be on **slide [1]** etc ....

Any help is much appreciated:

**Here's the code:**

```
 function videoviewsforloop(){



   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var awarenesstemplateId = "15q13aEt3MuHHnOnYyX6RE04bvnXk_B38qDWkowd5tzs";
  var awarenesstemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(awarenesstemplateId);
  var fileName = ss.getName();
  var copy = awarenesstemplate.makeCopy();
    copy.setName(fileName);
  var copyID = copy.getId();
  var slides = SlidesApp.openById(copyID);
  var defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();

var genderposition = {right: 30, bottom: 105};
var gendersize = {height: 300, width: 380};
var snapchatvideoviewsassheet = ss.getSheetByName('Snapchat Video Views Ad Set');
var snapcharts = snapchatvideoviewsassheet.getCharts();
 var snapchatvideoviewspostvalues = snapchatvideoviewsassheet.getRange ('A3:K32').  
 getValues();

 snapchatvideoviewspostvalues.forEach(function(row){

   if(row[0]){    

   var title = row[0]  
 
 defaultSlides[71].duplicate();
 defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();           
    var shapes = (defaultSlides[72].getShapes());
     shapes.forEach(function(shape){
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{title}}',title);
    });    

      for (var i = 0 ; i< snapcharts.length; i++){
      defaultSlides[72].insertSheetsChart
      (snapcharts[i],
      genderposition.right,
      genderposition.bottom,
      gendersize.width,
      gendersize.height); 
}
       defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();
       var presLength = defaultSlides.length; 
       defaultSlides[72].move(presLength);     
       defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();
   }
   });
  }
```

**Here's the sample spreadsheet**:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D6CNmM5yw4obRH3dADoBb059HJB4XNP29nUznw_iuXM/edit#gid=1410045588

Comment: `defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();` is duplicated on the `for` loop. This *might* not be the problem, but, its worth notice the duplicated code. Are you sure this is all the code you use for create the chart in each slide? - consider check closely the code.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes hello and thank you for your response. I have included all variables here so that they are retrievable. But the code is well structured in the sample spreadsheet If you have time to take a look. The problem lies in the function videoviewsforloop().

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I apologize. I understood what you meant. It is now corrected. I must've made a typo while pasting. It's all fixed now.

Comment: I've posted an answer that I think will help, since I see in your code you're looping all charts while on the row - that in my opinion is causing that all charts are added on every slide. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes You have no idea how much I've been trying to find the solution for this. It's been literally 8 months. A million thanks for this Marco!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code was modified. I remove the `for` loop used for loop the charts and instead, I use an index for set only the one chart per row.

Modified code:

```
function videoviewsforloop() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var awarenesstemplateId = "15q13aEt3MuHHnOnYyX6RE04bvnXk_B38qDWkowd5tzs";
    var awarenesstemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(awarenesstemplateId);
    var fileName = ss.getName();
    var copy = awarenesstemplate.makeCopy();
    copy.setName(fileName);
    var copyID = copy.getId();
    var slides = SlidesApp.openById(copyID);
    var defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();

    var genderposition = {
        right: 30,
        bottom: 105
    };
    var gendersize = {
        height: 300,
        width: 380
    };
    var snapchatvideoviewsassheet = ss.getSheetByName('Snapchat Video Views Ad Set');
    var snapcharts = snapchatvideoviewsassheet.getCharts();
    var snapchatvideoviewspostvalues = snapchatvideoviewsassheet.getRange('A3:K32').getValues();

    // This index will increase.
    var index_chart = 0;

    // For each row on the range of your sheet - i.e. "Snapchat Video Views Ad Set": 
    snapchatvideoviewspostvalues.forEach(function(row) {

        if (row[0]) {

            var title = row[0];

            defaultSlides[71].duplicate();
            defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();
            var shapes = (defaultSlides[72].getShapes());
            shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
                shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{title}}', title);
            });

            // Insert the chart on the slide: 
            defaultSlides[72].insertSheetsChart(snapcharts[index_chart], genderposition.right, genderposition.bottom, gendersize.width, gendersize.height);

            defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();
            var presLength = defaultSlides.length;
            defaultSlides[72].move(presLength);
            defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();
        }

        // Index increment. 
        // N.B. Move this index where you consider the row is ended - 
        // since I don't know what *if (row[0]) {* means here in your code.
        index_chart++;
    });
}
```